# Room with two database 'tables', 'foreign key' and 'live data'

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack

Trying to create room database with two related table one to one. Conncetion via **foreign key** work, but i found difficulties getting data with **live data**, I don't know if this correct to get data.

```
class GraphFragment : Fragment() {

   private lateinit var graphVM: GraphVM

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false)
        graphVM = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GraphVM::class.java)

        graphVM.graphFiles.observe(this, Observer<List<GraphEntity>> {
            it?.let {
                graphVM.getDataFiles( it.map { it.fileID })
            }
        })

        graphVM.dataFiles.observe(this, Observer<List<FileEntity>> {
            it?.let {
                // work with FileEntity
            }
        })
}
```

Viewmodel

```
class GraphVM(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

        private var graphFilesRepository: GraphRepository = GraphRepository(application)
        private var fileRepository: FileRepository = FileRepository(application)

        var graphFiles: LiveData<List<GraphEntity>> = MutableLiveData()
            private set

        var dataFiles: LiveData<List<FileEntity>> = MutableLiveData()
            private set

        init {
            // this work
            graphFiles = graphFilesRepository.getAllFiles()
        }

        fun getDataFiles(listOfFileIDs: List<Long?>) {
            // this not
            dataFiles = fileRepository.getFilesDataByID(listOfFileIDs)
        }
    }
```

FileRepository

```
class FileRepository(application: Application) {
    private var fileDao: FileDao

    init {
        val database: FileDatabase = FileDatabase.getInstance(application)!!
        fileDao = database.fileDao()
    }

    /..
    ../


    fun getFilesDataByID(listOfFileIDs: List<Long?>): LiveData<List<FileEntity>> {
        return fileDao.queryFilesEntityByID(listOfFileIDs)
    }
}
```

Dao

```
@Dao
interface FileDao {

    /..
    ../

    @Query("SELECT * FROM file_data WHERE id IN (:listOfFileIDs)")
    fun queryFilesEntityByID(listOfFileIDs : List<Long?>): LiveData<List<FileEntity>>
}
```

So, when I have assignment in init, live data is trigger correctly, but when I try to:

```
graphVM.getDataFiles( it.map { it.fileID })
```

**Livedata** is assignment, but don't trigger. I know it is assignment correctly, because when I remove, change values from FileRepository, **livedata** recive onChange and **observer** is inform. I would like to know is there any way to fix this, so I can use livedata to receive values from room database while assignments.

@PS found the problem. When I am trying to getDataFiles in Observer{...}, it dosen't work, but when I am calling function from onCreateView{...}, it work.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is you need observe and update one instance of `LiveData`, but call of `getDataFiles()` override `dataFiles` field.

Prefer solution is provide *request `LiveData`* to client and observe updates on client side:

```
class GraphVM(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    //...

    fun getDataFiles(listOfFileIDs: List<Long?>): LiveData<List<FileEntity>> {
        return fileRepository.getFilesDataByID(listOfFileIDs)
    }
}
```

If this approach is not appropriate, you can use `MediatorLiveData` to switch data sources:

```
class GraphVM(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var fileRepository: FileRepository = FileRepository(application)

    private val dataFiles = MediatorLiveData<List<FileEntity>>()
    private var request: LiveData<List<FileEntity>>? = null

    // expose dataFiles as LiveData
    fun getDataFiles(): LiveData<List<FileEntity>> = dataFiles

    @MainThread
    fun getDataFiles(listOfFileIDs: List<Long?>) {
        // create new request to repository
        val newRequest = fileRepository.getFilesDataByID(listOfFileIDs)
        val observer = Observer<List<FileEntity>> { list ->
            // remove previous subscription
            request?.run { dataFiles.removeSource(this) }
            // setup fresh data
            dataFiles.value = list
            // remember last request
            request = newRequest
        }
        // register new observable data source (LiveData)
        dataFiles.addSource(newRequest, observer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305882/combine-data-from-two-tables-in-room-viewmodel